# Unknown admin: ComponentInfo - Trying to enable kiosk mode for production Android device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to enable kiosk mode for my device but I'm getting an Unknown Admin error. I'm pretty sure I managed to set my app as device owner, and I think this is the last step, but this error is giving me a lot of trouble.

Manifest - I have a receiver here that should bind my application as device admin. It also refers to device_admin.xml which I'm not entirely sure I need; I made my device a device owner by rooting it and putting a device_owner.xml in /data/system. Is this different from device admin, and is the device_admin.xml necessary?

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.setupmanager.AdminReceiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        ...

    </application>
```

AdminReceiver - This never gets called in the current state. It SHOULD, I think, but it doesn't seem to be created right.

```
    public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Device Admin Enabled");
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.device_admin_enabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
            return context.getString(R.string.device_admin_warning);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, "device admin disabled");
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.device_admin_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLockTaskModeEntering(Context context, Intent intent, String pkg) {
            Log.v(TAG, "kiosk mode enabled");

            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.kiosk_mode_enabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLockTaskModeExiting(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, "kiosk mode disabled");

            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.kiosk_mode_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

device_admin.xml - This is just a blank xml file. Again, I'm not sure if I need it, or what purpose it holds.

```
    <device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    </device-admin>
```

MainActivity.java - OnCreate - Here is where I try to connect it all together. Judging by the log messages I get (trimmed down):

> > com.example.setupmanager/.AdminReceiver
> >
> > Not device admin
> >
> > Almost there...
> >
> > D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> >
> > E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> >
> > java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.example.setupmanager/com.example.setupmanager.AdminReceiver}

It seems I AM device owner, but ComponentName device admin is not created successfully from the AdminReceiver class.

```
    ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    if (deviceAdmin == null)
        Log.v(TAG, "No device admin exists");
    else
        Log.v(TAG, deviceAdmin.flattenToShortString());

    if (!mDpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Not device admin");
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_admin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Almost there...");
        mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{getPackageName()});
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Not device owner");
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_owner), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there any more info I should provide / steps to take? My device version is 5.0.2.

Edit:

When I type into the terminal connected to my device:
dpm set-device-owner com.example.setupmanager/MyAdmin

I get the error:
Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{com.example.setupmanager/MyAdmin}

...which is why I chose the root -> move device_owner.xml to /data/system method to make my app device-owner. I'm not sure if being unable to make my device admin through the terminal is connected to this problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your command for assigning the device manager is wrong
try

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.setupmanager/.AdminReceiver
```

This is according to [google codelabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cosu/index.html?#2)

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but I solved the error by changing the receiver name in the Manifest file from `com.packageName.util.reciever.AdminReceiver` to `.AdminReceiver` - followed by directly putting the Device Admin Receiver in the root of the package

After that Installing the app and running the command from ADB like ADB shell `dpm set-device-owner com.package.package/.AdminReceiver`

Comment: How much time it will take to get a response of this command? I have executed and I have been waiting from last 5 min but didn't get any success message into terminal.