# Setting device owner rights to the app on Samsung phone

Tags: android, adb, samsung-knox

I am trying to set my app as device owner via adb with this command:

```
dpm set-device-owner pl.my.packet/pl.my.packet.receivers.AdminReceiver
```

and then I see that error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL.,com.sec.enterprise.permission.MDM_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setActiveAdmin(IDevicePolicyManager.java:5825)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:145)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:96)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)
```

Phone: Samsung S7 Edge, not rooted, without any Google account linked.

I searched for other usefull threads for me but found nothing, I tried with these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.enterprise.permission.MDM_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" />
```

Comment: Do you actually need device owner mode?  Many of the functions that device owner mode provides are also available through the Samsung SDK.

Comment: @dkwiebe It is nice to be able to use standard techniques across hardware vendors.  Has Samsung broken this?

Comment: I got it working correctly on a Samsung device, so I think the answer to my question is no.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I gave up..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and found that I had typo-ed the package and receiver name in `dpm set-device-owner` command.  I don't think you need the package name in your receiver's name.  Maybe `dpm set-device-owner pl.my.packet/.AdminReceiver`?

Comment: This answer was down voted, but without explanation.  How should I improve it?

Comment: Upvoted. This is actually the answer! I had the same problem and with a few name changes, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Samsung phone and tried it with my emulator, so there was another Exception.

Turns out the AdminReceiver.class has to be in the root directory of your app:
com.example.yourRootPackage.MyAdminReceiver.class

Comment: Could you provide a reference for your solution?

Comment: I thought at least i want to run it on a not-samsung phone, because for work i developed already a kiosk mode app, so I came to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62921377/7173050 because without a Samsung phone i was getting an "unkown admin"-error. Hope it's what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Samsung Tablet (A6 with Android 8) recently and discovered a few things to consider:

0. (optional) You should probably add `android:testOnly="true"` inside your AndroidManifest.xml -> <application ...> and `android.injected.testOnly=true` inside your gradle.properties file to make sure that you can remove the device owner later with the `dpm remove-active-admin` command
1. There should be **no accounts present** in Settings->Accounts (delete all of them if any present)
2. Check the android:name you gave your receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml and write it down
3. use the format **< package-name >/< android:name of receiver class>** in your `dpm set-device-owner` command
4. make triple sure that there are no typos
5. check if there are already device owners present with `dumpsys device_policy`
6. check that you have the knox permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml (not 100% sure if neccessary)
7. your **AdminReceiver class can absolutetly be in a different package but you need to change your `dpm set-device-owner` accordingly** (see in examle)

---

So i will give an example how it worked for me:

My Package name is for example `de.my.cool.package`

My **AndroidManifest.xml** contains:

`<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.enterprise.permission.MDM_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" />`

`<application ..... android:testOnly="true">`

`<receiver android:name=".utils.AdminReceiver"`

**NOTICE:** my AdminReceiver is in its own package called `utils`.
My AdminReceiver class (the one that extends DeviceAdminReceiver) is therefore in `de.my.cool.package.utils.AdminReceiver`

AFTER installing the app i open an adb shell:

To add the device owner:

`dpm set-device-owner de.my.cool.package/.utils.AdminReceiver`

To remove the device owner:

`dpm remove-active-admin de.my.cool.package/.utils.AdminReceiver`

each command should not take more than a few seconds and there should be something written like
`Success: Device owner set to package ComponentInfo{de.my.cool.package/de.my.cool.package.utils.AdminReceiver}`

`Active admin set to component {de.my.cool.package/de.my.cool.package.utils.AdminReceiver}`

One of the important parts is that you add your additional package name from your AdminReceiver **AFTER** the `/` from the command and **NEVER BEFORE**.
Otherwise you will get weird errors that are not even the problem.

PS: a factory-reset also helped me immensely trying to solve this

Hope i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all accounts from your device.
then follow the steps

(1)Install application with android studio
(2) use Terminal or command prompt and run this command

dpm set-device-owner pl.my.packet/pl.my.packet.receivers.AdminReceiver

Answer (score -1):

> not rooted

You cannot do that as you are clearly told:

> Neither user 2000 nor current process has com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL.,com.sec.enterprise.permission.MDM_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL

And you cannot just add random permissions and expect it to work. I assume both are at least `signature` type or `system`. And you cannot have either on non rooted or not having system certificate.

Comment: This is not helpful.  It provides no alternative or solution.